# Open modal based on eventListener and cookie setting

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I've been having some trouble with this and I wanted to see if anyone could help me get some leads and or assist me on what I might be doing wrong and what I need to be doing.

*Please run the below script for a small example of mid page scrolling.*

**So here is what the script does**:

1. When a user loads the page and scrolls half way down the page, a modal will open and it will set a cookie that will expire in 30 days.

---

**So here are some things that I need help on**:

1. How do I check if there is a cookie set, and if there is, don't invoke the scroll event listener.
2. So inside the `trigger_modal` function, the `user_logged_in` element will return a boolean, which when logged into WordPress is true, otherwise it's false. How would I have the following conditional:

> If the user is logged in, don't set a cookie and keep opening the modal, otherwise if the user is not logged in, set the cookie and only open the modal if a cookie is not set.

---

**So here is the code that I have**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Trigger the scroll event listener.
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        // Select the modal element.
        let element = document.querySelector('.modalElement');
        // The element is in the viewport.
        if (is_in_viewport(element)) {
            // Trigger the modal
            trigger_modal(element);
        }
    });

    /**
     * Trigger modal
     *
     * @param element
     */
    function trigger_modal(element)  {
        // The correct modal_target gets pulled & user is logged in
        const modal_target = element.getAttribute('data-target');
        const user_logged_in = document.body.classList.contains('logged-in');

        // This grabs the correct stored cookie.
        let stored_cookie = get_cookie('acceptedPardot' + modal_target + 'Cookie');

        // If the cookie doesn't exist, set the cookie and allow for opening the modal
        if (!stored_cookie) {
            set_cookie('acceptedPardot' + modal_target + 'Cookie', 'true', 30);
            $(modal_target).modal('toggle');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set cookie
     *
     * @param name
     * @param value
     * @param days
     * @return {string}
     */
    function set_cookie(name, value, days) {
        let cookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
        if (typeof days === "number") {
            cookie += "; time=" + (days * 24 * 60 * 60);
            document.cookie = cookie;
            return cookie;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get cookie
     *
     * @param name
     * @return {string|null}
     */
    function get_cookie(name) {
        let cookie_array = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (let i = 0; i < cookie_array.length; i++) {
            const cookie_pair = cookie_array[i].split("=");
            if (name === cookie_pair[0].trim()) {
                return decodeURIComponent(cookie_pair[1]);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Check if element is in viewport
     *
     * @param element
     * @return {boolean}
     */
    function is_in_viewport(element) {
        const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        return (
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
        );
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<div class="modalElement" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-<?= $id ?>"></div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-<?= $id ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the logic you described.

```
function trigger_modal(element) {
  // The correct modal_target gets pulled & user is logged in
  const modal_target = element.getAttribute('data-target');
  const user_logged_in = document.body.classList.contains('logged-in');

  if (user_logged_in) {
    // If user logged in, show modal unconditionally
    $(modal_target).modal('toggle');
  } else {
    // This grabs the correct stored cookie.
    let stored_cookie = get_cookie('acceptedPardot' + modal_target + 'Cookie');

    // If the cookie doesn't exist, set the cookie and allow for opening the modal
    if (!stored_cookie) {
      set_cookie('acceptedPardot' + modal_target + 'Cookie', 'true', 30);
      $(modal_target).modal('toggle');
    }
  }
}
```